# ng-show doesn't work when the boolean flag is reset in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an input form where I am submitting details using `$http` in controller to server. On successful return, I want to give user alert that data is saved. But it is just not working and I am clueless after trying hard for many hours.

Here is the HTML code :

UI Code:

```
<div class="alert alert-success span-5 offset3" ng-show="message">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> The review has been successfully created.
</div>
```

And here is the controller logic, where I am flipping the flag.

```
$http.post('reviews/create',jsonData)
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.message=true
})
```

The response comes in the success block, which I have tested but then when I change flag 'message' status, the alert is not shown on UI screen. ng-show is not picking changes from $scope.message done in controller. Please suggest a solution. I tried making message as ng-model too using hidden field so that it's there in scope.
My view is visible in controller as i pulled out data and submitted successfully to the     server.

Comment: Please attach the whole controller to the post. You don't need to 'make the `message` an ng-model' in order to have it available on scope. Are you sure your view is actually inside the controller's scope?

Comment: Thanks for the clue.As i found out, the alert should also go in form tag where controller resides.It worked but if i again re-submit without refreshing the same page...it is again not showing up while the call goes to the server through controller